# PHP Remove everything except numbers from string

Tags: php

I am using AJAX to retrieve the ID of a certain HTML element. The HTML ID is constructed like "sqlitem_1", "sqlitem_2", "sqlitem_3" etc. and each number corresponds to a record in the database.

I tried `preg_replace('/\D/', '', $item);`where `$item` is the string I need to cut, but this didn't do the trick.

Comment: What was your exact code that you tried out?

Comment: `$item = $_GET['item'];
 preg_replace('/\D/', '', $item);
 // Haal alle non-nummeristic characters uit de string $item.
 
 echo json_encode($item);`

Comment: And the outcome is just the same string..

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. `preg_replace` doesn't change the original value but rather returns the new one. You might wanna check [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace). So you should do `$item = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $item);` instead.

Comment: Yeah! Great, it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Would you like me to add an answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please note that `preg_replace` doesn't change the argument but rather returns the new value. You might wanna check the [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) manual.
So what you need to do is assign the returned value

```
$item = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $item);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done either server side (PHP) or if you wanted to preserve the variable name you could use the JavaScript Split function.

**JS Split Function (Client Side)**

```
var myVar = "sqlitem_1";
var tmp = str.split("_");
```

and then access each element using tmp[0] etc

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

OR

**PHP (Server Side)**

```
$ITEMTMP=explode("_", $item);
$itemnumber=$ITEMTMP[1];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php